# Unable to add highlights in epubjs using a context Menu(React)

Tags: reactjs, epub, epub.js

I am creating an epub viewer and using react-reader as my npm package to render the file. I am trying to highlight the text when selected. The documentation does provide a way to do it. But the approach I am trying is to open a context menu and only when the "Hightlight" button is selected then it should highlight the text.
[image: This is how the context menu looks like]

This is the code for the reader page:

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ReactReader } from "react-reader";
import Notes from "../_components/Notes";
import Discussions from "../_components/Discussions";
import { Rendition, Contents } from "epubjs";
import { get } from "http";
import ContextMenu from "../_lib/ContextMenu";

type ITextSelection = {
  text: string;
  cfiRange: string;
};

const initialContextMenu = {
  show: false,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
};

function Reader() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<string | number>(0);
  const [discussions, setDiscussions] = useState("showDiscussions");
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [selections, setSelections] = useState<ITextSelection[]>([]);
  const [rendition, setRendition] = useState<Rendition | undefined>(undefined);

  const handleSearch = () => {
    // Perform search logic here
  };
  function setRenderSelection(cfiRange: string, contents: Contents) {
    if (rendition) {
      setSelections((list) =>
        list.concat({
          text: rendition.getRange(cfiRange).toString(),
          cfiRange,
        })
      );
      rendition.annotations.add("highlight", cfiRange, {}, undefined, "hl", {
        fill: "yellow",
        "fill-opacity": "0.3",
        "mix-blend-mode": "multiply",
      });
      const selection = contents.window.getSelection();
      selection?.removeAllRanges();
      console.log(selection);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (rendition) {
      // rendition.on("selected", setRenderSelection);
      rendition.on("selected", (rendition: Rendition, iframe: Window) => {
        console.log("Rendition rendered");
        iframe.document.documentElement.addEventListener(
          "contextmenu",
          (event: MouseEvent) => {
            console.log("Stopping contextual menu coming from epubjs iframe");
            event.preventDefault();
            setcontextMenu((prev) => ({
              show: true,
              x: event.pageX,
              y: event.pageY,
            }));
          }
        );
      });
      console.log(selections);
      return () => {
        rendition?.off("selected", setRenderSelection);
      };
    }
  }, [setSelections, rendition]);

  const [contextMenu, setcontextMenu] = useState(initialContextMenu);

  function handleContextMenu(e: React.MouseEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("right click");
    const { pageX, pageY } = e;
    setcontextMenu((prev) => ({
      show: true,
      x: pageX,
      y: pageY,
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div className="h-screen">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-3 gap-3 h-screen">
        <div className="row-span-3 h-screen py-2 rounded-lg">
          {/* Reader Section */}
          <div className="h-full rounded-lg" onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}>
            <ReactReader
              url="https://react-reader.metabits.no/files/alice.epub"
              location={location}
              locationChanged={(epubcfi: string) => setLocation(epubcfi)}
              getRendition={(_rendition: Rendition) => {
                _rendition.themes.default({
                  "::selection": {
                    background: "rgba(255,255,0, 0.3)",
                  },
                  body: {
                    color: "black",
                    fontSize: "1.2em",
                    textIndent: "2em",
                    lineHeight: "1.6",
                    padding: "0",
                    margin: "0",
                  },
                });
                setRendition(_rendition);
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row-span-2 bg-white mt-2 mr-2 rounded-lg overflow-hidden ">
          {contextMenu.show && (
            <ContextMenu x={contextMenu.x} y={contextMenu.y} />
          )}
          {/* Discussions/ Notes Section */}
          <div className="w-full h-16 rounded-s-lg">
            <div className="h-full bg-white rounded-lg">
              <div className="h-full  rounded-lg">
                <div className="flex justify-evenly items-center pt-4 h-full w-full">
                  <button
                    className={`h-full w-full m-2 rounded-lg ${
                      discussions === "showDiscussions"
                        ? "bg-textColor text-white"
                        : "bg-white"
                    } `}
                    onClick={() => setDiscussions("showDiscussions")}
                  >
                    Discussions
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className={`h-full w-full m-2 rounded-lg ${
                      discussions === "showNotes"
                        ? "bg-textColor text-white"
                        : "bg-white"
                    }`}
                    onClick={() => setDiscussions("showNotes")}
                  >
                    Notes
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="h-full mb-4 overflow-scroll scroll-m-0">
            {discussions === "showDiscussions" ? <Discussions /> : <Notes />}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-start-2 row-start-3 mb-2 mr-2 bg-white rounded-lg">
          {/* 
          Profile Section
          */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Reader;
```

And here is the code for the context Menu:

```
import { FC } from "react";

interface IContextMenu {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const ContextMenu: FC<IContextMenu> = ({ x, y }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="context-menu"
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: y + 50,
        left: x + 250,
        zIndex: 10000,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        border: "1px solid #ccc",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        padding: "0",
        margin: "0",
      }}
    >
      <ul className="list-none">
        <li
          className="hover:bg-gray-200 p-2 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("Copy");
          }}
        >
          Copy
        </li>
        <li
          className="hover:bg-gray-200 p-2 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("Highlight");
          }}
        >
          Highlight
        </li>
        <li
          className="hover:bg-gray-200 p-2 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("Bookmark");
          }}
        >
          Bookmark
        </li>
        <li
          className="hover:bg-gray-200 p-2 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("Note");
          }}
        >
          Note
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContextMenu;
```

Does anyone have any intuition as to how should i go about it?